# Dojo Grid refuses to sort by Date. How to get this to work?

Tags: dojo, dojox.grid, dojox.grid.datagrid

I have a Dojo Grid with a date column. Despite using a custom formatter, it always does a string sort. Note that my incoming dates will be formatted as 02/17/2005 and I cannot change that.

```
formatDate = function(d){
return dojo.date.locale.format(new Date(d), {datePattern: "M/dd/yyyy", formatLength: 'short', selector: "date"});
}

var myData= [
{field: "transactionDate", name: "Transaction Date", width: "115px", datatype: "date", formatter: formatDate  },
{field: "description", name: "Transaction Description", width: "170px" },
]];

var storeData = {
items: [
  {
  transactionDate:"04/15/2011",
  description:"A description of the transaction"
  }
  ,
  {
  transactionDate:"04/15/2011",
  description:"A description of the transaction"
  }
  ,
  {
  transactionDate:"04/15/2011",
  description:"A description of the transaction"
  }
  ,
  {
  transactionDate:"04/15/2011",
  description:"A description of the transaction"
  }
  ,
  {
  transactionDate:"02/15/2010",
  description:"A description of the transaction"
  }
  ,
  {
  transactionDate:"01/15/2011",
  description:"A description of the transaction"
  }
  ,
  {
  transactionDate:"04/15/2011",
  description:"A description of the transaction"
  }
  ,
  {
  transactionDate:"09/15/2009",
  description:"A description of the transaction"
  }
  ,
  {
  transactionDate:"04/15/2011",
  description:"A description of the transaction"
  }
  ,
  {
  transactionDate:"04/15/2011",
  description:"A description of the transaction"
  }
]};
```

---

```
 <div class="claro" style="width: 835px; height: 300px;">
    <div dojotype="dojo.data.ItemFileReadStore" jsID="dataStoreForGrid" data="storeData"></div>
    <div id="grid" dojotype="dojox.grid.DataGrid" store="transferStoreForGrid" clientSort="true" jsID="SomeId" structure="myData" rowsperpage="40" ></div>
  </div>
```

---

Per Peller's suggestion, I tried formatting as ISO date. Thais had no affect on sorting:

```
    formatDate = function(d){
var d2 = dojo.date.stamp.fromISOString(ISODateString(new Date(d)));
return dojo.date.locale.format(d2, {selector: 'date', formatLength: 'long'});
}

function ISODateString(d) {
function pad(n){
return n&lt;10 ? '0'+n : n
}
return d.getUTCFullYear()+'-'
+ pad(d.getUTCMonth()+1)+'-'
+ pad(d.getUTCDate())+'T'
+ pad(d.getUTCHours())+':'
+ pad(d.getUTCMinutes())+':'
+ pad(d.getUTCSeconds())+'Z'
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the [example in the docs](http://docs.dojocampus.org/dojox/grid/DataGrid#formatting-a-date-field).  I think you just have to use ISO format for the date (yyyy-mm-dd) which is generally good practice anyway.  You may be able to pass in native Date objects also, but strings are obviously more portable.

Comment: See my edit above -- Sorting still doesn't work correctly when passing in an ISO date string.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't mean to format as as an ISO date, I meant to use the ISO date format in your data :)  because ISO dates have the wonderful property of sorting in alphabetical order.  To do this without modifying the incoming data, you'd probably have to change the way the data store does its sorting.

Answer (score 0):

thin, you need a WriteStore rather than a ReadStore